# HTML5 video does not autoplay on Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

Can anyone tell me why this HTML5 video isn't working? It works fine in Firefox, but not in Safari or Chrome. Can't seem to figure out what's going on.

Here's the page I'm working on http://www.adventures.org/trips/?prg=passport&new=design.

The video is behind the big Passport logo.

Here's the video code.

```html
<video autoplay loop  muted class="fillWidth">
  <source src="http://adventures.org/trips/video/PassportHeader.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="http://adventures.org/trips/video/PassportHeader.webm" type="video/webm" />
                Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
</video>
```

**Thanks for all the suggestions! I finally figured it out. The video codec was having an issue with the Facebook API located in my footer.**

Comment: I'd suggest adding a 3rd video type, .ogg. I believe that would actually cover you properly across browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Brant. I have added the .ogg but it didn't make a difference. I can copy the code out of this page, past it into any other page and it works fine. Something on this page is killing the video...

Comment: Show the code ..please..

Comment: Just added the video block in my post @scaisEdge.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you use @j08691?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that browser is confused with two source that you set. Try this:

```
<video autoplay loop  muted class="fillWidth">
  <source src="http://adventures.org/trips/video/PassportHeader.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try check canuse video tag at  this http://caniuse.com/#feat=video

seem there are some issues with codec in safari for `webm`

> Will work in IE9+ and Safari/MacOSX provided the user has the WebM
>   codecs installed. Partial support indicates that at least one codec is
>   supported but not all.

check inside notes and key issues http://caniuse.com/#feat=webm

Comment: Shouldn't it fall back to the mp4 if Safari has problems with webm? I would think it would.

Comment: See if you need a right codec i think there is a reference in canuse   and if my answer is useful please rate it